# how to model and train a PyTorch Model to to learn a mathematical function f(x)?

Tags: function, pytorch, neural-network

I'm currently learning how to use pytorch to model NNs and did the "Getting Started" Session on the PyTorch Website.

I tried to train a PyTorch NN to apply the function e.g. f(x)=2x-1 to a given input integer list but my model is far apart from learning the right thing.

How can I model and train a PyTorch model to learn a given mathematical function f(x) ?

I've tried this model and trained it with 10 random numbers with labels generated by the 'myFunc' function to learn the function 2x-1.

Thanks for your help.

```py
batch_size = 10

def myFunc(a):
    #y = 2x-1
    return 2*a-1

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(batch_size,1)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(1,batch_size)
        

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.lin2(x)
        return x

model = NeuralNetwork()
```

Comment: Please add your code for being able to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 10 training samples is not enough. Try with much more. 1000 or more.

Answer (score 1):

The anwser for simple linear functions of type y = ax+b is:

```py
class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(Model,self).__init__()
        self.linearLayer = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        pred = self.linearLayer(x)
        return pred
```

with the train loop

```py
model = Model()
crit = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr = 0.01)

#main train loop
for epoch in range(1000):
    y_pred = model(x_data)
    loss = crit(y_pred,y_label)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

hopefully I didn't forget anything important...

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically for your example of an affine-linear function over a bounded interval you need only

```
linear(bias) -> relu -> linear(bias)
```

with one node per linear layer. Or just one linear layer without activation.

For more general functions, you will need larger layers in the construction of the first type, with one node for every piece in a piece-wise approximation. The last layer always needs to be linear without activation. Using more layers might give more pieces with less total nodes.

Comment: What if I wanna have a model that is able to learn a function of type ax^2+bx+c? How does an example of a model look like?

Comment: As said, with relu activation all you will ever get are piecewise linear functions. The error is proportional to the square of the segment length, so with enough segments you can get the error over a bounded segment arbitrarily small. There is no way to get a quadratic function naturally from the network structure.